# Finding the smallest $n$ such that $\sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n < \epsilon$?

Tags: inequality, epsilon-delta

I am trying to solve for a lower bound $N_{\epsilon, \delta}$ on $n$ such that $$n \geq N_{\epsilon, \delta} \implies \sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n < \epsilon$$
holds, where $\epsilon > 0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$. I've tried applying the inequality $1 + nx \leq e^{nx}$, and using logarithms, but I can't figure this out. Could someone please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Ditch the $\sqrt{n}$ and apply $\log$ to both sides. You get $$n > \frac{\log\epsilon}{\log(1-\delta^2)}$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi ditch?

Comment: see the fleshed out comment. Ditch means lose the term

Comment: @NinadMunshi Could you please be more specific -- $$(1 - \delta^2)^n \leq \sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n$$ so I can't just ignore the term?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you can do

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\epsilon > \sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n > (1-\delta^2)^n$$

which gives us

$$\log \epsilon > n\log(1-\delta^2) \implies n > \frac{\log\epsilon}{\log(1-\delta^2)}$$

The inequality flips after the division because the $\log$'s are negative.

Comment: But $(1 - \delta^2)^n < \epsilon$ does not imply that $\sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n < \epsilon$.

Comment: Why do you want it to go backwards? You never specified the context in your post, which you are supposed to do, by the way.

Comment: Note that not dropping $\sqrt{n}$ yields an additional factor $\ln(n)/2$, so this estimate can be improved by a factor of 2.

Comment: What do you mean backwards? I clearly stated that I am trying to solve: $\sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n < \epsilon$.

Comment: @ProofIsTrivium right, and if you assume that equation, then it is true that $$\sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n < \epsilon \implies (1-\delta^2)^n < \epsilon$$ so why do you want to go backwards?

Comment: You have to remember that inequalities are not equations. There is an ambiguity when you say "solve" because lines between equalities are "if and only if"s whereas you can see here the same is not true for inequalities.

Comment: I think we may have miscommunicated here. Fixing $\epsilon > 0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$, it is clear that $$\sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$. My question asks, how can I solve explicitly for a positive integer $N_{\epsilon, \delta}$ such that $$n \geq N_{\epsilon, \delta} \implies \sqrt{n}(1 - \delta^2)^n < \epsilon.$$

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium I didn't want to rely on this, but there is a "direct" method where you immediately get the inverse function to $na^n$ via the $-1$ branch of the Lambert W function $W_{-1}$. However I will keep trying to think of something more elementary